# Control Lightbox (Modal) From Code-Behind Of Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, lightbox

Before meeting with Ajax and Jquery, in my projects I had a function like below.

```
Public Sub Raise_Alarm(ByVal p_Page As Page, ByVal p_Message As String, Optional ByVal p_IsError As Boolean = True)

strScript = "<script language= ""javascript""> alert('" & p_Message.Replace("'", "") & "')</script>"
    Dim t As Type = p_Page.GetType()
    p_Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(t, "alert", strScript)
    Dim mylabel As Label

end sub
```

For now I want to a function instead of function above, which show message as a lightbox (modal box).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use jqModal as suggested by cxfx above (+1;), this should work:

```
strScript = "$('<div>" & p_Message.Replace("'", "\'") & "</div>').jqm();";
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(p_Page.GetType(), "alert", strScript, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the excellent jQuery plugins for displaying modal windows such as [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/).  The docs explain how to configure and launch your modal window, and include some great examples.

Comment: I have already looked it, but I ask for how to use it in a function in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "thickbox" it can just display a noraml aspx page in a modal window.  You can then use code behind as normal.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link href="/themes/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />       
<link runat="server" href="/styles/thickbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />       
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/thickbox.js"></script>      

</head>
<body>
       <a class="thickbox" href="mylink.aspx?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=300&width=850">modal thick box link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In fact, I tried to use it, but ı couldn't. Can you write sample code please.

Comment: This is super.I was in search for the same thing .Thanks Jon